# Moving the first value of an array arg into xmm0

Tags: assembly, x86, disassembly

I have a function which subtracts a 3D vector like this in C:

```
inline void sub(float* a, float* b, float* r) {
  r[0] = a[0] - b[0];
  r[1] = a[1] - b[1];
  r[2] = a[2] - b[2];
```

And Visual Studio shows me in debug disassembly for the first assignment the following:

```
r[0] = a[0] - b[0];
0078BBA8  mov         eax,4  
0078BBAD  imul        ecx,eax,0  
0078BBB0  mov         edx,4  
0078BBB5  imul        eax,edx,0  
0078BBB8  mov         edx,dword ptr [a]  <------ i guess: reading a[0]
0078BBBB  mov         esi,dword ptr [b]  
0078BBBE  movss       xmm0,dword ptr [edx+ecx]  <------ i guess: write a[0] to xmm0
0078BBC3  subss       xmm0,dword ptr [esi+eax]  
0078BBC8  mov         eax,4  
0078BBCD  imul        ecx,eax,0  
0078BBD0  mov         edx,dword ptr [r]  
0078BBD3  movss       dword ptr [edx+ecx],xmm0
```

Me as a newbie in assembly I just don't get why the following line uses `[a]` instead of `a`:

```
0078BBB8  mov         edx,dword ptr [a]
```

I would have expected that in `edx` we should have the pointer address itself instead of the value at the pointer because the following line seems to read the value from the address in `edx`:

```
0078BBBE  movss       xmm0,dword ptr [edx+ecx]
```

Could anybody give me a hint why this works?

Comment: @Sep: I think "an array parameter" was a better title.  "a parameter array" would more normally be interpreted as an array *of paramaters*, not an array (of float) that is a *single* function parameter.  The rest of your edit is good, though.

Comment: @PeterCordes OK, I blame it on me not being a native English speaker. In Dutch this inversion makes a little more sense...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is how the debugger shows the disassembly for the function, but it is a bit misleading: `a` is not the same thing as it is in the C source code. The actual instruction which is shown as `mov edx, dword ptr [a]` is

```
8B 55 08     mov edx, dword ptr [ebp+8]
```

`a` is used as the name for `ebp+8` to simplify reading the disassembly.

Since this is 32bit code and the default calling convention for that passes all parameters on the stack, `a` itself is not directly available, it must be read from the stack first, which is what you're seeing.